# No puedo importar variables de un Entry tkinter o un dataframe de un archivo.py a otro

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Actualmente tengo un script que realiza calculos complejos con liberias estadisticas a base de un dataframe, Pero hace unos dias me solicitaron implementar una GUI que ingrese 2 parametros por consola, programe una GUI super basica con tkinter pero no logro pasar los valores de los Entry y el df a mi otro script, dejo un ejemplo de un codigo sencillo, con la respuesta espero adaptarlo a mi codigo real.

interfaz.py

```
##!/usr/bin/python
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from menu import *

def getvalues():
    value1 = float(X.get())
    value2 = float(Y.get())
    return value1, value2

def anotherPY():
    Tk().withdraw() 
    filename = askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
    menu.sum1()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Project")

X = tk.Entry(root)
X.pack()
X.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c")

Y = tk.Entry(root)
Y.pack()
Y.place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c")

b1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Calculate", width = 15, command = anotherPY)
b1.pack()
b1.place(relx=.5, rely=.9, anchor="c")


root.mainloop()
```

menu.py

```
from interfaz import value1, value2, df
import pandas as pd

def sum1():
    value3 = value1 + value2
    print(df)
    print(value3)
```

The error output is:

```
C:\Users\Jota\Desktop\Modulos>interfaz.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jota\Miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in 
__call___
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Jota\Desktop\Modulos\gui.py", line 13, in anotherPY
    menu.sum1()
NameError: name 'menu' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jota\Desktop\Modulos\interfaz.py", line 5, in <module>
    from menu import *
  File "C:\Users\Jota\Desktop\Modulos\menu.py", line 1, in <module>
    from interfaz import value1, value2
ImportError: cannot import name 'value1' from 'interfaz' 
(C:\Users\Jota\Desktop\Modul
os\interfaz.py)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Toma en cuenta que la inicializacion de la variable prueba como la funcion en el modulo a importar,capturo los datos mediante la funcion o metodo get() y envio mediante set() pero estos solo funcionan si la variable contenedora es StringVar() o IntVar.

[image: codigo]